# Prove that $f(x) ≥ f(x^∗) + α||x − x^∗||\iff 0 ∈ \text{int}\ ∂f (x^∗)$

Tags: analysis, convex-optimization

Assume that $f$ is a convex function, and $x^*$ is the minimizer of the function.

Prove that the inequality $f(x) ≥ f(x^*) + α||x − x^*|| (α > 0)$ holds if, and only if, $0 ∈ \text{int}\ ∂f(x^*)$.

I have been stuck on this problem from over a week now, and was hoping to get some help from you guys.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is unclear what “int” is. The edits were meant to be combined

Comment: @ТymaGaidash int this case, int means the interior of the subdifferential.